# Gulp browser-sync where place folder?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I installed plugin Browser-sync. At command line a paste `gulp browser-sync` and at firefox is displayed "*Cannot GET /*" for adress `http://localhost:3000/`

In the *gulpfile.js* are:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
 var files = [
  'app/**/*.html',
 ];

 browserSync.init(files, {
  server: {
     baseDir: './app'
  }
 });
});
```

Folder ***app*** is placed in the root of Node.js. I do not use any LAMP or WAMP because I can not use it. Is some other way for solve to issue? (reload page in browser after change source code).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because Browser sync does not know, without additional configuration, what to do when you do not specify the explicit file you want to view. Normally, web servers default to viewing index.html when a directory is specified.

To see if this is the case, go to `http://localhost:3000/index.html`, assuming you have an index.html directly under the 'app' directory (e.g. app/index.html exists).

To 'fix' this, add one of the following parameters to the server configuration:

1. `index: "index.html"` (display index.html)
2. `directory: true` (display a directory listing)

For more configuration options, see http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

Additionally, the first parameter is probably unnecessary. I suggest trying the following

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
 browserSync.init(null, {
  server: {
     baseDir: 'app',
     directory: true // or index: "index.html"
  }
 });
});
```

Apparently in newer versions of browser sync it can be intialized with simply `browserSync({ /* options */});`, see http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/